# rubygem pg not installing after using rubymine

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems, rvm, rubymine

I tried out rubymine for the first time and changed the Postgresql settings and now the gem won't install. Below is the copy of the error after trying to install the gem. The below was run after I deleted the Rubymine app and the files it created.

```
Aris-MacBook-Pro:~ arikalmen$ gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/arikalmen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/pg-0.21.0/ext
/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20171221-20772-masvtl.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/arikalmen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.4.0/pg-0.21.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/arikalmen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/pg-0.21.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/arikalmen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.4.0/pg-0.21.0/gem_make.out
Aris-MacBook-Pro:~ arikalmen$
```

The pasted below was in the before mentioned mkmf.log

/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.4.0/pg-0.21.0/gem_make.out

```
ind_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- no

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib     -lruby.2.4.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/arikalmen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
"mkmf.log" [readonly] 31L, 2722C
```

Comment: The error message tells you to show at `mkmf.log` for more details. Did you do that?

Comment: i did. not sure what to make of it. I'll post it as an answer because it's too long.

Comment: Please edit your question and post it there. A log is not an answer.

Comment: yes sir. thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

First, install the missing library:

```
brew install libpqxx
```

then follow the steps in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301476/gem-install-pg-for-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I think I'm having conflict between the Graphical installer by BigSQL that i installed and the Postgres.app found on the download pag3 [link](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/)

I removed the Graphical installer from my apps, but I sense it's still there because the default postgresql port(5432) is still being occupied. Figured that out from this question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100368/postgresql-port-confusion-5433-or-5432)

Answer (score 0):

The above error message says:

> checking for libpq-fe.h... no
>
> Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header

Installing this should fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

You need specify ARCHFLAG, Try this：
`sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`